# Visual Studio Debugger not breaking on Debug Assertion Failure

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a problem with the VS debugger, it won't break into my code anymore if a debug assertion failure occured. It just stops execution/debugging, even if I press `Retry`. It happens for example if I have a vector subscript out of range:

```
std::vector<int> a(4);
a[4]=0;
```

I started a new project (just a button on a window, executing the above), and there it correctly broke, so I guess it is a settings issue. I did not find any helpful settings so far. 
I recently moved some files in my project folder, so that might have triggered this problem.

Any suggestions? I am sorry if this questions happens to be answered elsewhere in this forum, I did not find it.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you building the debug or release configuration?

Comment: Where is your assertion? I don't see any assert statement in your post.

Comment: @doctorlove it's debug configuration.

Comment: @DanielDaranas What I meant is that execution should fail when encountering that code. VS gives a message stating sth like 'Debug Assertion Failed... vector subscript out of range', and gives me the possibility to debug. But the `Retry` button just finishes execution)

Comment: It's possible that the debug service has worked itself into an unusable state. If you are launching the application in the debugger and it doesn't break into the assertion try restarting your computer.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious restarting did not help, well at least shutting down and rebooting on the next morning..

Answer (score 0):

The [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) function does not do any bounds checking, so you have undefined behavior which may, or may not, cause a crash.

The [`at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) function will throw an exception when indexing out of bounds though.

Comment: Misusing `operator[]` was just an example, to trigger the failure. The actual problem is that I can't get into the line of code where it failed..

Comment: @cauchy42 If you use `at` instead, and run a debug build in the debugger, it should stop the moment the exception is thrown. Then just walk up the call-stack to your function.

Comment: Yes that worked. However, the `operator[]` was just an example. In fact I am using std::list and iterators. But the real problem is that the debugger does not break..

Comment: @cauchy42 That's the thing about _undefined behavior_, it's undefined and so anything can happen. Sometimes there's a "crash", sometimes there's not, sometimes it causes [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). You simply can't expect undefined behavior to behave in any specific way.

Comment: I agree that I might have undefined behaviour in my code. But when at runtime the 'Microsoft Visual C++ Debug Library' notices an error and prompts me to press `Retry` if I want to debug, then that should work regardless of undefined behaviour, shouldn't it? And it does not...

Comment: @cauchy42 If you run in the debugger, you won't even get that dialog, it will just stop at the error. Have you tried that instead? In fact, the crash may actually be something different than you expect it to be, and can't be caught the way you want it to.

Comment: after following your advice I was at least able to find the faulty piece of code: At one point I actually tried to increment a past-the-end iterator, which is a rather stupid idea. But I feel like that only circumvents the real problem I have. OK, I don't see it anymore, but anyway...

Comment: @Justin I would say that the undefined behavior is indeed a reasonable answer. Undefined behavior means that the behavior can't be predicted, and that it can include somehow making the debugger not work as expected. Heck, it might even cause [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) to appear.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I can accept "the debugger and/or compiler seems to have a bug", but the OPs comment on 5/30/2013 10:44 - "Yes that worked. However, the operator[] was just an example. In fact I am using std::list and iterators. But the real problem is that the debugger does not break." leaves me to believe there is a more global problem, as different code has the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try these

1) Make sure you have array bounds checked in your configuration settings. On some versions of visual studio, this is switched on by default even in release builds! It's possible that a purist developer has switched this off for all configurations and you've inherited these settings.

2) Check your project configuration settings. Are you running a debug build?

3) Rebuild everything. i.e. Rebuild All.

4) If still not fixed, delete all intermediate files yourself and Rebuild All.

5) Hardcode a breakpoint with the line `__asm int 3;`

Comment: 1) Where do I find that setting? 2) It is a debug build. 3) + 4) did not help.. 5) I used that code (double underscore...) near the point where I expect the error, and it's producing compiler errors now (I am using managed code inside a native function, but that appeared to work before). I removed the native code and it compiled, and then finished, probably at that point. Could you please explain the __asm statement?